# Setting reference frame for shapefile with pyshp?

Tags: python, shapefile, python-3, pyshp

I'm using pyshp to create new shapefiles with Python 3. My code runs without errors, but when I open the resulting file in ArcMap I get this error:

> The following datasource you added is missing spatial reference information.

This is not surprising, since I never told my code that the coordinates in the shapefile are supposed to be in EPSG:3006. How do I set this property in pyshp?

Here's some short example code. I want to tell the writer `shape` that the coordinates in `start` and `stop` are in EPSG:3006.

```
import shapefile

start = [6400137, 321751]  # Coordinates in EPSG:3006
stop  = [6400095, 319357]  # Coordinates in EPSG:3006

with shapefile.Writer("my_shapefile") as shape:
    shape.fileType = 3 # Polyline
    shape.field("FOO", "C", size = 32)
    shape.field("BAR", "C", size = 32)
    shape.line([[start, stop]])
    shape.record("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Unlike [osgeo.ogr](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/), [Fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) or [GeoPandas](https://pypi.org/project/geopandas/), [Pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) doesn't manage  projection files (look at [Create a .prj Projection File for a Shapefile](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/create-prj-projection-file-for.html))

Comment: Thanks @gene! Your comment, and especially the last link, solved my problem. If you would post it as an answer I would be happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2):

Information about the coordinate system is stored in a separate projection file, that should have the same name as the shapefile, but a .prj extention.

As [gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2581/gene) points out in comments, the Pyshp library doesn't handle projection files. So you will have to write the file yourself. [Here's](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/create-prj-projection-file-for.html) an example of how to do that:

```
# create the PRJ file
prj = open("%s.prj" % filename, "w")
epsg = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",'
epsg += 'DATUM["WGS_1984",'
epsg += 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]]'
epsg += ',PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],'
epsg += 'UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
prj.write(epsg)
prj.close()
```

If you want to find the correct file content for your coordinate system, I recommend you simply create a shapefile with that coordinate system in e.g. ArcCatalog, and then just copy paste the content of the created projection file.